# How to execute selenium script/batch using java

Tags: java, selenium

Would like to execute selenium script/batch scripts using java. Based on input parameters to call script/batch scripts.

To understand, how to run script/batch using java code.

Please help me out here.

Comment: Why did you try?

Comment: Provide some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to run a bash script contained in a file in a java project, use the ProcessBuilder class like this:

```
ProcessBuilder procBuildScript = new ProcessBuilder ([your_script_path],arg1,arg2,...);
procBuildScript.start();
```

So you can pass arguments after your script path
as "script.sh",arg1,arg2

For example :

```
public void runMyScript(String aFirstArg, String aSecondArg){

     ProcessBuilder procBuildScript = new ProcessBuilder("./your-script.sh",aFirstArg,aSecondArg);
     procBuildScript.start();

}
```

In your script you can call these arguments using the expressions $ 1, $ 2 ... $ {10}, $ {11} corresponding to the index where the desired parameter is located :

```
#!/bin/bash
# your-script.sh

echo "First argument is : $1"
echo "Third argument is : $3"
```